# How to get a document's custom fields through DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to access the custom field values for documents that I download. I am able to list the completed envelopes and download the documents, but the custom fields are showing up as empty?

```
var docFields = envelopeApi.ListDocumentFields(AccountID, envelopeId, docId);
Console.WriteLine(docFields.DocumentFields.Count);
```

`Count` is always zero even though the custom fields have been filled in by the user?

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint which you calling is to download the document custom fields which is added by the sender as the metadata of the document. It will not help you in downloading the form data entered by the signer on the document. To download form data via API, you can use `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/form_data`, more details available at [getFormData DS Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get). You can also use to download tab details for the recipients using `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs`, more details available at [Download Recipient tab data](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/list)

Most recommended way is to setup [DS Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect) so that you do not have to poll DS API to get envelope status or form data etc, instead host a webservice on your side and configure the same in DocuSign so that DocuSign can push the required data to your webservice in an XML format.